Moveit2 Pick and Place without Task Constructor
I have the custom moveit package of Fanuc CRX-10iA/L and I am trying to achive the Pick and Place operation on Rviz with mock_components/GenericSystem controller by using the following Moveit2 Cpp interface classes/methods:

moveit::planning_interface::PlanningSceneInterface
moveit_msgs::msg::CollisionObject
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface

I don't want to use Task Constructor because I have written a smach base task organizator for multiple pick and place operations. However I can't find the equivalent of move_group.pick("object", grasps) in Moveit2.
You can find the relevant code snippet which was taken from Github below.
void pick(moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface& move_group)
{
    std::vector<moveit_msgs::Grasp> grasps;
    grasps.resize(1);

    // Grasp pose
    grasps[0].grasp_pose.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    tf2::Quaternion orientation;

    // Pick Test 2
    orientation.setRPY(tau/4, -tau/4, 0);
    grasps[0].grasp_pose.pose.orientation = tf2::toMsg(orientation);
    grasps[0].grasp_pose.pose.position.x = 1;
    grasps[0].grasp_pose.pose.position.y = 0.085;
    grasps[0].grasp_pose.pose.position.z = 0.5;

    // Pre-grasp approach
    grasps[0].pre_grasp_approach.direction.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    // Direction is set as positive x axis
    grasps[0].pre_grasp_approach.direction.vector.y = -1.0;
    grasps[0].pre_grasp_approach.min_distance = 0.095;
    grasps[0].pre_grasp_approach.desired_distance = 0.115;

    // Post-grasp retreat
    grasps[0].post_grasp_retreat.direction.header.frame_id = "base_link";
    //Direction is set as positive z axis 
    grasps[0].post_grasp_retreat.direction.vector.z = 1.0;
    grasps[0].post_grasp_retreat.min_distance = 0.1;
    grasps[0].post_grasp_retreat.desired_distance = 0.25;



    // we need to open the gripper. We will define a function for that
    openGripper(grasps[0].pre_grasp_posture);

    // When it grasps it needs to close the gripper
    closedGripper(grasps[0].grasp_posture);

    // Set support surface as table 1
    move_group.setSupportSurfaceName("table1");

    // Call pick to pick up the object using the grasps given
    move_group.pick("object", grasps);

    
}

What would be your solution to this issue?
Any help is really appreciated. Thank you...
